# Getting a copy of an instance of NSManagedObject class in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an instance of `Addon` class (inherited from `NSManagedObject`) `foundSampleAddon`. I want to create a copy of this instance of class and mutate its properties. I am trying to copy this instance using the following code but I am not sure how to achieve it as I am getting an exception

> -[Addon copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d1d805000

I dont know how to create copy of this instance of class using the `copyWithZone:` function. I have posted the code below where I am trying to copy `foundSampleAddon` into a new identity, `sampleAddonToAdd` and then changing its property `productAddonPrice`.

```
if let sampleAddonToAdd = foundSampleAddon.copy() as? Addon {
        if addonCategoriesSent![sentIndexPath!.section].replacePreviousBasePrice == 1 {
             sampleAddonToAdd.productAddonPrice = NSNumber(int: 0)
        }
        addonsToAddBackToProduct.append([keyAnAddon: sampleAddonToAdd, keyAddonCount: 1])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> NSManagedObject does not conform to the NSCopying protocol. If you
>   want to create a new record with the same data, just insert a new
>   object and assign the values from the first object to the second
>   object.

[As said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974701/nsmanagedobject-copywithzone-issues)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a second `NSManagedObject` and copy the properties.

```
let sampleAddonToAdd = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Addon", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! Addon
sampleAddonToAdd.productAddonPrice = foundSampleAddon.productAddonPrice.copy() // copy properties
```

Then modify the properties you want to.

Comment: This initilization wont have properties of foundSampleAddon saved in it, which i want to achieve. I want a copy and not an initialization

Comment: You have to make the copy yourself is what I'm saying. Copying all the properties gets you a copy of the object.

Comment: but some of the properties of the class itself are reference to another class, what to do about them?

Comment: You mean reference to a different instance? You can copy references just fine.

Comment: sorry i meant instances of another class. If i copy them, any mutation to it will be reflected in both `Addon` objects

Comment: If you want to deep copy a whole data structure, you will have to implement your own copy methods, that also create copies of referenced objects.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i am going to make a workaround.

Comment: It would be nice if you post your solution here.